# Explanation for Perl format function

Tags: perl

```
if( $start =~ /^(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$/) {
        my @t = ( $6, $5, $4, $1, $2-1, $3);
        $event->{start} = timelocal(@t);
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me this code?

Comment: looks like the string $start is a timestamp in the format "dd.mm.yy HH:MM:SS". Then you're assigning the "start" key of the $event hashref (or object) to the epoch timestamp of that time.

Comment: Which part do you have problems understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which part of it don't you understand?

```
# $start is a string.
# We match $start against a regular expression.
# The regular expression looks for:
# * The start of the string [^]
# * One or more digits [(\d+)]
# * Any single character [.]
# * One or more digits [(\d+)]
# * Any single character [.]
# * One or more digits [(\d+)]
# * One or more whitespace characters [\s+]
# * One or more digits [(\d+)]
# * A colon [:]
# * One or more digits [(\d+)]
# * A colon [:]
# * One or more digits [(\d+)]
# * The end of the string [$]
# Each of the sets of digits that are matched are "captured".
# That means that if the regex matches, the digits are stored
# in variables. The first set of digits is put in $1, the
# second set of digits is put in $2, and so on.
if( $start =~ /^(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$/) {
    # If the regex matches, then we execute this block of code.
    # We copy the capture variables into an array called @t
    # We copy them in a different order to how they appear
    # in the original string.
    # We subtract 1 from $2 before using it.
    my @t = ( $6, $5, $4, $1, $2-1, $3);
    # We pass @t to a function called timelocal() which we
    # have loaded from a module called Time::Local.
    # timelocal() takes a list of date/time values and returns
    # the number of seconds since 00:00 on 1970-01-01.
    # $event is a hash reference. We store the number of seconds
    # as the value against the "start" key in the referenced 
    # hash.
    $event->{start} = timelocal(@t);
}
```

From this, we can work out that the original string which probably contained a timestamp in the format `DD MM YYYY HH:MM:SS` and we are converting it into the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00.

This could be achieved far more simply using `strptime` from [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).

```
use Time::Piece;

$event->{start} = Time::Piece->strptime($str, '%d $m %Y %H:%M:%S')->epoch;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like someone is excessively badly reimplementing `POSIX::strptime`. In particular, it's just matching and capturing various number ranges out of the original string into the numbered capture buffers.